# Haskell ghci lambda symbol in prompt

Tags: haskell, terminal, prompt, ghci

In Haskell ghci is it possible (and how) to get a lambda symbol in the prompt, for instance like this

```
λ>
```

Using Linux Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `:set prompt`. Follow it by whatever you want the prompt to be. You can put this in `.ghci`, I believe.

```
:set prompt "λ> "
:set prompt2 "λ| "
```

Comment: Thanks a heap, is it possible to use unicode in set prompt for example for value 03BB which denotes the lamda symbol ?

Comment: To add to MathematicalOrchid's answer, you should write the following two lines in your `.ghci` file: `:set prompt "λ> "`, `:set prompt2 "λ| "`.

Comment: `Q: But where do I put the .ghci file?` 
A: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html

Comment: Since at least GHC version 8.2.1, `prompt2` has been replaced by `prompt-cont`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following command to use the lambda character:

```
:set prompt "\x03BB: "
```

Comment: Or something like `:set prompt "%s\n\x03BB "` if you want to see the loaded modules on the first line, and the `λ ` on the second line.